# League Fractal including multiple nested relationships

Tags: nested, include, relationship, thephpleague-fractal

How can I include multiple child relationships using `?include=`?

Example:
`/store/1?include=books.author:downloads`

The result would produce:

```
[
    id: 1,
    name: 'Book Name',
    author: {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Author name'
        }
    },
    downloads: {
        data: {
            weekly: 100,
            monthly: 1000
        }
    }
]
```

I left out most of the object, just the core of what I'm requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you simply include `books` twice and it knows to merge them together.

So:
`/store/1?include=books.author,books.downloads`

It would be nice to have that documented somewhere. If it is and I've missed it please let me know.